# Measuring distance polygons to lines with sjoin_nearest() in GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, spatial-join, proximity, vector-layer

I am trying to use GeoPandas `sjoin_nearest()` function to measure the distance from polygons to lines. I have several polygons and I am measuring the distance to the river, which is the green line.

This is what the data looks like:

[image]

The red polygons are called *'ny_shapes'*. The green line is called *'ny_river'*.

Here is the code:

```py
ny_shapes = ny_shapes.sjoin_nearest(ny_river, distance_col="dist_to_river")
```

The resulting DataFrame measures the distance, but all distances are nearly the same:

```py
print(ny_shapes['dist_to_river'])
0    985493.874583
1    985493.629073
2    985493.572803
```

Why? Am I using the `sjoin_nearest()` function incorrectly?

Comment: What coordinate system is it?

Comment: With those distances I suspect one shapefile is in a local UTM while the other is in lat/lon.

Comment: What is `ny_shapes.crs` (before your join) and `ny_river.crs`?

Comment: You are all correct. The crs is different for each layer. This solved the problem.  Thank you for bringing this obvious mistake to my attention!

Comment: @ErichPurpur can you please put this comment as an answer to your own question ^_^